# How can I make multiple VMs work on the same script in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a Python script which is supposed to create quite a lengthy list, currently the VM I am using has an 8 core processor and 30GB RAM however that is not enough as the machine runs out of memory before it can generate the list.
I am wondering, is it possible to have say 5 similar VMs and have them work on the same script and pool their resources together? I was thinking of using a MIG however I am wondering where would I then store the script and how would they be able to communicate among them?

Comment: You need a great amount of compute power there. Have you considered using multiprocessing or threading in Python?

Comment: There are options to spin up a server with the amount of memory greater than 30G, did you consider going down this route?

Comment: You didn't mention whether the nature of the problem allows it to be parallelizable.   Are you looking for a solution where, today, you are processing Y input items on one VM and are looking to process the same work on 5 X VMs where each processes Y/5 items?

Comment: Distributed computing to achieve the same thing on several server is a very complex operation. It's better to consider the computation of smaller part in parallel (that each distributed computing pattern do, with reconciliation at the end).

Comment: Your question needs more details. You have not shown the script. You have not included information on if the script supports clusters of systems such as Hadoop.

Comment: @lukas will have a look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this issue by changing my Python script to use a generator instead of saving the list to a var and simply for loop through that generator, no need for extra processing power.